# What is the structure of PduK in the Pdu BMC?

Tags: bacteriology, protein-structure, structural-biology, synthetic-biology, xray-crystallography

My lab is creating [1,2-propanediol utilization bacterial microcompartments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacterial_microcompartment#PDU_BMCs) (Pdu BMCs) with an operon containing genes for PduA, PduB, PduJ, PduK, PduN, PduU, and PduT. According to [Mayer *et al.*](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep36899), all of these Pdu proteins form homohexamers, except for PduN, which forms homopentamers. Additionally, all of these Pdu proteins, except for PduK, can be found in the [Protein Data Bank](https://www.rcsb.org/). Where can I find information on the structure of PduK in the Pdu BMC? Is there a reason for this apparent lack of PduK crystallography data online?

Comment: If the structures of all the other Pdu gene products are in PDB, then presumably the structure of PduK has not been determined for Lactobacillus reuteri. Why this is so is anyone’s guess. May be difficult to crystallize, group run out of money, in progress etc.  Best to email the lead author, Yeates, and enquire. (And thanks to @acvill for pointing out  that I'd got  the genes confused in my answer, now deleted.)